# ajax, if successful refresh after 3 seconds

Tags: ajax

title says it all, the way the script currently works is if its successful, it brings back a message back from my php code, i want it to also refresh the page after 3 seconds

```
$(function(){
        $('button[type=submit]').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "postadvert.php",
                data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#result').html('<div class="success"><img src="../../images/loading-blue.gif" width="25" /></div>');
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $('#result').html(data),
                    $('#result2').html('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">'); // i added that doesn't working
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` in combination with `window.location.reload(true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.  First, you need a semicolon after your first line in the success function.  Next, you can use the setTimeout function in javascript where you pass a function and a time to wait in milliseconds.  Lastly, you can call the location.reload() to refresh the page.

```
success: function(data){
   $('#result').html(data);
   setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the following in your success callback:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { 
  document.location.href = document.location.href; 
}, 3000);
```

Assigning to `document.location.href` automagically causes the browser to load the URL so assigned; assigning its own value back to it therefore causes a refresh. The `window.setTimeout()` call tells the browser to wait three seconds, then run the function given as its first argument.